# XML Parsing in PLSQL

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, oracle10g

I have a below format XML and need to insert the data into a table.

The data is dynamic and needs to be insert into PL/SQL table. Could you please guide me how to solve this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Result>
     <Name SN="ABC" PID="PID1">
       <Name SN="111" PID="P01" />
        <Name SN="222" PID="P02" />
     </Name >
     <Name SN="PQR" PID="PID2">
        <Name SN="100" PID="P04" />
        <Name SN="200" PID="P05" />
        <Name SN="300" PID="P05" />
        <Name SN="400" PID="P06" />
     </Name >
 </Result>`
```

Query :

```
        SELECT XXCSS_AUTOTEST_INPUT_OBJ (
                  SUBSTR (
                     EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                     INSTR (
                        EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                        '"',
                        1,
                        1)
                     + 1,
                     INSTR (
                        EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                        '"',
                        1,
                        2)
                     - INSTR (
                          EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                          '"',
                          1,
                          1)
                     - 1),
                  SUBSTR (
                     EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                     INSTR (
                        EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                        '"',
                        1,
                        5)
                     + 1,
                     INSTR (
                        EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                        '"',
                        1,
                        6)
                     - INSTR (
                          EXTRACT (VALUE (P), '/Device').getstringval (),
                          '"',
                          1,
                          5)
                     - 1))
          BULK COLLECT INTO p_auto_test_out
          FROM TABLE (
                  XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (l_xml_file, '//Result/Device'))) P;
```

I'm able to read the fist two tags ABC and PQR and unable to read the child tags.

Comment: What is the error? Can you post your sql as well?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the below SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample SQL which might help you. Tweak it as per your needs. There is lot of documentation available online on querying xml in SQL. You can follow those examples to write complex queries.

```
Declare @xml XML ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Result>
     <Name SN="ABC" PID="PID1">
       <Name SN="111" PID="P01" />
        <Name SN="222" PID="P02" />
     </Name >
     <Name SN="PQR" PID="PID2">
        <Name SN="100" PID="P04" />
        <Name SN="200" PID="P05" />
        <Name SN="300" PID="P05" />
        <Name SN="400" PID="P06" />
     </Name >
 </Result>'


SELECT  mytable.mycol.value('(../@SN)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') [Parent SN],
        mytable.mycol.value('(../@PID)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') [Parent PID],
        mytable.mycol.value('(@SN)[1]','INT') [SN],
        mytable.mycol.value('(@PID)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') [PID]
FROM    @xml.nodes(N'/Result/Name/*') AS mytable(mycol)
```